# How to average groups of columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Given the following pandas dataframe:

[image: Picture of dataframe loaded into pandas. Figure 1]

I am trying to get to point b (shown in image 2). Where I want to use row 'class' to identify column names and average columns with the same class. I have been trying to use setdefault to create a dictionary but I am not having much luck. I aim to achieve the final result shown in fig 2.

Since this is a representative example (the actual dataframe is huge), please let me know of a loop based example if possible.

[image: Final result aim. Figure 2.]

Any help or pointers in the right direction is immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Imports and Test DataFrame

```py
import pandas as pd
from string import ascii_lowercase  # for test data
import numpy as np  # for test data

np.random.seed(365)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 6) * 1000, columns=list(ascii_lowercase[:6]))
df.index.name = 'Class'

                a           b           c           d           e           f
Class                                                                        
0      941.455743  641.602705  684.610467  588.562066  543.887219  368.070913
1      766.625774  305.012427  442.085972  110.443337  438.373785  752.615799
2      291.626250  885.722745  996.691261  486.568378  349.410194  151.412764
3      891.947611  773.542541  780.213921  489.000349  532.862838  189.855095
4      958.551868  882.662907   86.499676  243.609553  279.726092  215.662172
```

### Create a DataFrame of column pair means

```py
# use list slicing to select even and odd columns
even_cols = df.columns[0::2]
odd_cols = df.columns[1::2]

# zip the two lists into pairs
# zip creates tuples, but pandas requires list of columns, so we map the tuples into lists
col_pairs = list(map(list, zip(even_cols, odd_cols)))

# in a list comprehension iterate through each column pair, get the mean, and concat the results into a dataframe
df_means = pd.concat([df[pairs].mean(axis=1) for pairs in col_pairs], axis=1)

# in a list comprehension create column header names with a string join 
df_means.columns = [' & '.join(pair) for pair in col_pairs]

# display(df_means)
            a & b       c & d       e & f
Class                                    
0      791.529224  636.586267  455.979066
1      535.819101  276.264655  595.494792
2      588.674498  741.629819  250.411479
3      832.745076  634.607135  361.358966
4      920.607387  165.054615  247.694132
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
df['A B'] = df[['A', 'B']].mean(axis=1)
```

Comment: While this answer may answer the question it would be good if you explained the code a bit, e.g. why it is built that way, how it works etc.